# Http or Https in order to connect to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, http, google-cloud-functions, sim900

Im trying to connect a SIM900 (which is not capable of SSL) to Firebase function. I use Get/Post Methods with an Https URL. I was told that Firebase function accepts both HTTP and HTTPS. Im trying to pass sensor data from SIM900 to my Firestore.

When I use HTTPS, it gives me an error of 603 (DNS Error).

```
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://us-central1-*****.net/data_values?ph=10"
AT+HTTPACTION=1
```

RESPONSE

```
:HTTPACTION=0,603,0
```

When I remove "s" and insert only HTTP, it gives me an error of 302(Redirect Error).

Firebase function is already configured and working properly.

I tried connecting the SIM900 to several post/get test servers but it only tends to connect to HTTP-only websites.

Any suggestions or solutions on how will I be able to connect them?

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly what you're doing to make the request and observe the response.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: HTTP?? Really? I'm almost sure that you aren't able to do this. @DougStevenson is far more better than me on this special trick.